# Does the Duergar race have racial feats available in D&D 4th edition?

Tags: dnd-4e, feat-qualifications, dwarf, duergar

Duergar has been introduced as a PC race in Monster's Manual 3 if I'm correct. I have found no sight of additional Duergar rules if any other book for D&D 4th edition. I was wondering if Duergar has been designed so that it can be treated as a Dwarf when it comes to acquiring racial feats, racial paragon, or epic paths.

Comment: Duergar get a racial stat block in Monster Manual 2, where they first appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  As with other monster races that did not receive a Dragon Magazine article, Duergar do not have additional support.  They also never received a flexible stat (most races were updated to get +2 to one statistic and +2 to one of two others, but Duergar are stuck with Con and Wis only).  And because they aren't explicitly able to access Dwarf feats, they can't do so.